# Извлечение из целого числа определенное количество битов C#

Tags: c#, .net, bit

Необходимо написать универсальный метод, который позволит из целого без знакового (Uint32) извлечь определенный фрейм битов и преобразовать выделенный фрейм снова в целое число (Int32), в разных комбинациях.

Пример (жирным выделены фреймы, которые необходимо получить):
Число = 4194967295 = 1111 10100000101000011110 11111111

1111 **10100000101000011110** 11111111

Далее

111 **1** 10100000101000011110 11111111 - тут все просто, для извлечения одного конкретного бита, написан отдельный метод с вот таким содержанием:

```
value & (1 << (bitNumber));
```

Потом

1111 101000001010000111 **10** 11111111

1111 10100000101000011110 **11111111**

- Метод называется GetBitFrame
- Возвращает целочисленное (int)
- Первый параметр - исходное число целое без знаковое(uint)
- Второй параметр - размер кадра (количетво бит, которые необходимо выделить из целого числа)
- Ну и параметры, например для сдвигов влево-вправо (short, int не важно).

Я сделал так, но это работает не правильно:

```
private const uint Value = 4194967295;

private int GetBitFrame(short leftShift, short rightShift)
    {
        if (leftShift < 0 || leftShift > 31 || rightShift < 0 || rightShift > 31)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        var buffer = (int)((Value << 1) >> leftShift); // откинул справа на leftShift
        var result = buffer << rightShift; // откинул влево на rightShift

        return result;
    }

    public int TwentyBitFrame => GetBitFrame(9, 4); // Тут должен получить 10100000101000011110 DEC = 657950
```

Comment: 1) Неплохо бы проверять корректность задания границ, т,е, что левый край левее правого. 2) При получении результата вы сдвигаете buffer влево на rightShift, но забываете, что при формировании buffer УЖЕ сдвинули исходное число вправо на leftShift

Comment: Извиняюсь, за удаленный комментарий, не сразу понял задачу) `value << left >> (left + right)` - избавляемся от левых битов сдвигом влево, затем от правых битов сдвигом право (учитывая прошлый сдвиг)

Comment: `(int)((Value << 1) >> leftShift)`  еквивалентно (по крайней мере для leftShift > 1)  `(int)((Value >> (leftShift-1))` Вот тут и возникает вопрос, почему вы сдвигаете на `leftShift-1` а не на `leftShift` ?  А почему тогда справа не вычитаете? Мне кажется что данная операция - лишняя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делаем в два этапа.

У нас есть параметры `source` (откуда извлекаем биты), `position` (с какого места), `length` (длина фрагмента).

С позицией проще всего — надо сдвинуть `source` вправо на `position` бит, чтобы убрать все младшие (правые) биты.

Чтобы избавиться от старших битов, нужна маска, у которой нижние `length` бит равны 1, а старшие `32 - legnth` бит равны 0.

Берём беззнаковое значение из всех единиц (`uint.MaxValue`) и сдвигаем вправо на `32 - legnth` бит. При сдвиге беззнакового числа пустые биты будут заполняться нулём.

Итого:

```
static uint GetBitFrame(uint source, int position, int length)
{
    Debug.Assert(position >= 0);
    Debug.Assert(length > 0);
    Debug.Assert(position + length <= 32);

    return (source >> position) & (uint.MaxValue >> (32 - length));
}
```

Тест:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    uint test = 0b1111_1010_0000_1010_0001_1110_1111_1111;
    var result = GetBitFrame(test, 8, 20);

    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(test, 2));
    Console.WriteLine("    " + Convert.ToString(result, 2));
}
```

Вывод:

```
11111010000010100001111011111111
    10100000101000011110
```

Comment: Блестящий ответ! Огромное спасибо Вам и всем участникам дискуссии!

Comment: Имхо, @John предложил лучший вариант в комментариях.

Comment: У меня результат не сходится. Думаю из-за того что не накладывается маска.

Comment: @JDo, напишите числа, которые передаёте. `source`, `position` и `length`.

Comment: @Mark Shevchenko ваш вариант отлично работает! Ответ адресовался Михаилу Муругову.